# How to get shell command output to ansible variables file

Tags: ansible

I need to set variable in defaults\main.yml to something like:

`eth1_ipaddress: {% /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk -F ' *|:' '/inet addr/{print $4}' %}`

Is there a way to achieve this?
I know this can be achived using shell and register module. But that is not what I am looking at since I need to add certain conditions before setting the variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hostvars facts like this:

```
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth1']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

Make sure that you set:

```
- hosts: whatever
  gather_facts: yes
```

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts